# Android DBHelper Upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite, mozilla

I have a mozilla sqlite for my android App.
in the sqlite manager on my firefox, i'm add a row to my table.and when i run program, the database not updated.

so i change my oncreate and upgrade method as bellow:

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Db_City");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST Db_City");
    onCreate(db);

}
```

and change the version of my database.

but when i run the program again all of my data in app is missing.

can anybody help me to exactly what to do?
tanks.

Comment: *can anybody help me to exactly what to do?* sure, you should not delete the data ... obviously `DROP TABLE` do this ... also ... i assuming that *mozilla sqlite* mubmla jumbla means that you wana persist database ... then you should use library pointed in bazillion questions about persisted sqlite database

Comment: On the one hand when you add new row or something else in your database code then you must change the version of your database in order your app get the changes..On the other hand when you change your database version refreshing your db and you lost all your data...that's it..

Comment: You haven't posted nearly enough code to adequately figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the table deletes all the data in the table.

1. You need to copy the data somewhere (probably best to rename it).
2. delete database (probably best to rename it).
3. create a new database.
4. re-load  (and probably convert) the data.